# Many to many relationship in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a blog web app that uses React, and Firebase. And there are 2 different collections as posts and tags. Each post has several tags also each tag belongs to several posts. Can someone help me to handle many to many relationships?[image: post collection]

[image: tags collection]

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?